# IndexedDB "The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. "

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm creating a script to read an attribute from a database - due to the architecture of the project it's easiest if this is implemented in JS.

I'm using IndexedDB, and I can find the database successfully, but when I try to get an attribute from the objectStore I'm getting an error (It seems I'm not able to access the Table):

**Firefox:** "NotFoundError: The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened."

**Chrome:** NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

My code:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("/app_name/database.sqlite", 1);
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    console.log("Found Database");
    db = event.target.result;

    var transaction = db.transaction(["TABLE"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("TABLE");
    var ob = objectStore.get(String(ATTRIBUTE));

    ob.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Got ATTRIBUTE")
    }
    ob.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Have not got ATTRIBUTE")
    }

}
request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log("Database not found");
}
```

The error occurs on the line `var transaction = db.transaction(["TABLE"], "readonly");`.

The TABLE does exist - when the database is opened in a viewer the attribute is there.

I have not used `.onupgradeneeded` since I am not creating any new objectstores - rather just trying to read one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use IndexedDB to read from an existing SQLite file. That's not going to work. IndexedDB is self-contained within the browser, it doesn't have anything to do with external files. The only way to create object stores is to do it in `onupgradendeeded`, and then you will also have to write the code to load data into them.

If this is a Cordova app, maybe [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) or [this](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2) is more what you're looking for.